# A fantasy book about a woman who can speak with animals and is taken by the prince?

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I think I read this around 2009 and my dad got it for me from a used book store so it could be much older.

What I remember from the story is that it follows a girl who lives in isolation in a cottage with a bunch of animals with whom she can speak. She grows into a beautiful woman and the people from the surrounding kingdom are all scared of her (I think she's some kind of sorceress). She is taken by the prince of the kingdom and I think she ends up marrying the king. Reluctantly at first but then falls in love with him. I'm pretty sure the king is also overturned from the throne at one point in the book.

If I remember correctly, the cover was purple/blue and had a sort of a garden or jungle with different animals in it.

I've been trying to find this book for so long please help!!

Comment: I think i know what book your looking for, my wife keeps trying to have me read it and it has a similar plot and book cover asking her what the name was now.

Comment: Maybe [_The Forgotten Beasts of Eld_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forgotten_Beasts_of_Eld).  Similar but some details differ.

Answer (score 1):

[*Wild*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Wild.html?id=DUCdaoL1qJMC) by Jill Barnett may be what your looking for:

> Shunned by superstitious villagers, Teleri of the Woods learned early
>   that the world is a frightening place. For years she has lived hidden
>   away in a dark forest, where her only friends are the creatures of the
>   woods. But when she finds a gravely wounded knight, her sanctuary is
>   safe no more. With his legendary skills in war and diplomacy, Roger
>   FitzAlan had been sent to establish a stronghold on the Welsh
>   borderlands. Ambushed and left to die by an unknown enemy, Roger must
>   now battle for more than his life -- he must win the trust and love of
>   the wild young woman who has every reason to fear him.

[image: Book cover]